# How do you set a background image to position itself dynamically in a mobile browser in landscape mode

Tags: html, css

I want a background image to position itself dynamically when a mobile browser is in landscape mode;

This is the code that I wrote to attempt this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
<body style="margin:0; background-image: url(example.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:100%;"></body>
</head>
</html>
```

It doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
background-size: cover;
```

This will make your image fit the entire container. Also, remove `width=100%`;